# How to set up IAM Roles Anywhere with your own CA (using openssl) and CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I struggled setting up IAM Roles anywhere with a CA generated with OpenSSL
and also deploy it with CDK (or Cloudformation)

Question: How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step by step for IAM Roles Anywhere with your own CA (using openssl) plus deployment with CDK (can easily be used for Cloudformation)

check it out:
https://medium.com/cyberark-engineering/calling-aws-services-from-your-on-premises-servers-using-iam-roles-anywhere-3e335ed648be